# iPhone - How to use #define in Universal app

Tags: iphone, universal-binary

I'm creating universal app that runs oniphone and ipad.
I'm using #define to create CGRect. And I want to use two different #define - one for iPhone and one for iPad.
How can I declare them so that correct one will be picked by universal app..........

I think I've to update little more description to avoid confusion.
I've a WPConstants.h file where I'm declaring all the #define as below

```
#define PUZZLE_TOPVIEW_RECT CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 100)
#define PUZZLE_MIDDLEVIEW_RECT CGRectMake(0, 100, 480, 100)
#define PUZZLE_BOTTOMVIEW_RECT CGRectMake(0, 200, 480, 100)
```

The above ones are for iphone. Similarly for iPad I want to have different #define
How can I proceed further?

Answer (score 2):

As recommended by Apple, use

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { ... }
else { ... }
```

to write platform-specific code. With the ternary `?:` operator, you could also incorporate this into a `#define`:

```
#define MyRect (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768) : CGRectMake(0,0,480,320))
```

In case you wanted to use conditional compilation to determine which of two `#define` statements should be included in your code, you can't: a universal app does not contain two separate binaries for iPhone and iPad. It's just one binary so all platform-related decisions have to be made at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the info. You mentioned CGRectMake for only one rect. Please see my updated description.

Comment: Well, you would obviously repeat the process three times. BTW, I wouldn't work with `#define`s. Why not just declare a variable and define it according to the platform you're running on.

Comment: Thanks again. Can you tell me how to declare variables account to the platform I'm running on?

Comment: Just declare a variable: `CGRect puzzleTopViewRect;`, then set its value depending on the result of `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`.

Answer (score 1):

i used this function to detect iPad, and then write conditions for all different parts of my application.

```
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    #define isPad() (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#else
    #define isPad() NO
#endif
```

Also you can load different xib files for iPhone/iPad.

Comment: #ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM is broken in Xcode 6.3+ as it is no longer a preprocessor define